# TSQL - Matching a date between two dates in another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I currently have two tables, **tbl_Invoices**

```
InvoiceNumber  NextBillingDate
------------------------------
    100            3/15/21
    200            3/31/21
    300            4/15/21
    400            5/15/21
```

and **tbl_GLPeriods**:

```
GLPeriod     PeriodStartDate     PeriodEndDate
----------------------------------------------
  250            3/3/21              4/3/21
  251            4/4/21              5/2/21
  252            5/3/21              6/3/21
```

I need a view that returns a column where the GL period for the next billing date is provided, ie:

```
InvoiceNumber  NextBillingPeriod
---------------------------------
    100              250
    200              250
    300              251
    400              252
```

How do I query to find if one column is between the two columns in another table? I'm blanking on how to do this, thinking something with a `CASE`.

Edit: where I'm currently at, structurally won't work, but it shows what I'm currently trying to get going:

```
SELECT
    *,
    CASE
       WHEN tbl_Invoices.NextBillingDate BETWEEN (SELECT PeriodStartDate FROM tbl_GLPeriods) AS stdt 
                                             AND (SELECT PeriodEndDate FROM tbl_GLPeriods) AS endt  
          THEN endt.GLPeriod    
    END AS NextBillingPeriod
FROM
    tbl_Invoices
```

Solved with this thanks to @Charlieface:

```
select tbl_Invoices.InvoiceNumber, tbl_GLPeriods.GLPeriod 
from tbl_Invoices
left join tbl_GLPeriods on tbl_Invoices.NextBillingDate between tbl_GLPeriods.PeriodStartDate AND tbl_GLPeriods.PeriodEndDate
```

Comment: You should try something and [edit] the question to include that attempt along with an explanation what's wrong with it.

Comment: What do you want to do if the invoice date is not in the periods table?

Comment: Return a null, actually the majority of invoices in the table don't have these dates but I need the GL period in instances where they do.

Comment: A `left join ... on tbl_Invoices.NextBillingDate BETWEEN ...` works?

Comment: @Charlieface that did the trick, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AND` to connect multiple predicates to check for a range with `<=` and `>` (or equivalent). Like that you can use a correlated subquery similar to what you've tried, provided the periods cannot overlap.

```
SELECT i.invoicenumber,
       (SELECT p.glperiod
               FROM tbl_glperiods p
               WHERE p.periodstartdate <= i.nextbillingdate
                     AND dateadd(DAY, 1, p.periodenddate) > i.nextbillingdate) nextbillingperiod
       FROM tbl_invoices i;
```

You can also use a left join. Then the periods can overlap, you'll get multiple rows, if a date falls in two or more periods. A join might also perform better.

```
SELECT i.invoicenumber,
       p.glperiod nextbillingperiod
       FROM tbl_invoices i
            LEFT JOIN tbl_glperiods p
                      ON p.periodstartdate <= i.nextbillingdate
                         AND dateadd(DAY, 1, p.periodenddate) > i.nextbillingdate;
```

Note that you can shorten `dateadd(DAY, 1, p.periodenddate)` to just `p.periodenddate` if `tbl_glperiods.periodenddate` is meant to be and exclusive upper bound or if it's inclusive but `tbl_invoices.nextbillingdate` is guaranteed not to be more precise than a day, i.e. it cannot have an hour, minute, second and so on portion. Otherwise you might miss timestamps on the last day past midnight.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  InvoiceNumber, 
  (
    select 
      GLPeriod 
    from 
      tbl_GLPeriods 
    where 
      NextBillingDate between PeriodStartDate 
      and PeriodEndDate
  ) 'NextBillingPeriod' 
from 
  tbl_Invoices
```